# Request to re-open interesting question (not mine) after editing

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

Recently, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292929/rounding-fairness-optimization-in-r) was put on hold as off-topic because it asked for an off-site resource. In the orginal question, the OP asked if there was a R-package that could solve this problem, and apparantly 5 users considered asking for a package off-topic.

I think that is a pity, because IMHO it is an interesting problem that might be useful to others. So both the OP and myself edited the question, so that it no longer asks for a package, but for a smart solution, rather than crude calculations. It is true that OP shows little effort in solving the question, but that is because he couldn't think of a smart solution.

I would finally like to emphasize that the question is not mine and also that I haven't thought of a smart solution (yet). And as a <3K user, I can't vote to re-open.

Comment: First para still asks for a package....I think some more editing is required

Comment: @Paulie_D oops, overlooked that. Edited! (hopefully not to minor).

Comment: I like that question. Voted to reopen.

Comment: question now re-opened